# solution for a real-time client-server socket programming between ionic and windows approaches (like asp.mvc, iis, ...)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, socket.io, ionic2

I'm implementing server/client solution with real-time interaction. I use windows approaches (`Asp.mvc` published on `IIS` web server) as server and a mobile App (ionic approach) as Client.

I'm locking for a solution to interact with the mobile App developed by `ionic` using **WebSocket programming**.

I also find some good modules like 'Ionic socket.IO', But it needs `Nodejs` at server, meanwhile i have use `IIS` as webserver.

Does anyone have any clue, how to implement and establish socket based communication between server (`asp.mvc`) and client(`ionic mobile app`).

It's notable that **"I cannot switch to a total new framework (both in server and client)"**. I mean i cannot switch from `asp.mvc` to any other frameworks like `Nodejs` as server-side webserver; At the mean time, I cannot re-develop already developed ionic app to any other frameworks (like `phonegap/react-native` etc...)

--------------------------- EDITED -------------------------------------
My software suppose to be a full two way binding solution. As i already mentioned, It is **Real-Time** solution (like a stock trader software). means that App can send data to server and **server can send data to App as well**.

I have already lunched a `webApi`.

mobile app can call exposed WebApi functions. **but there should be a way for server to push new events to specific cellphone**. the `WebSocket` is the answer for sure.
I'm wondering to know "If there is a way (component or manner) to connect to `ionic` developed App from server and push new data into target cellphone"?

**By the way! vote for closing this message, may frustrate others who have the same scenario**

Comment: you may want to create a web API here

Comment: @ RAHUL S R please lock at the edited question.

Comment: you should look in SignalR with webapi

Comment: @ RAHUL S R So exactly. why don't you put it as answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using IIS already you need a web api to communicate with your mobile app asp.net WebAPI si the way to go and use Signal R with webAPI

https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api